# Streaming a JSON document to a Rest web service with java

Tags: java, json, api, rest, streaming

I've seen examples where you can use a http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html from a Rest api so that the restful respones can be a Json stream. This makes it so you can start processing JSON tokens as they come in instead of waiting until the whole thing is there.

Now i'm interested in the other way.

The flow:

1. The client opens a stream to a Rest api endpoint.
2. The client starts sending data through the stream.
3. The server while reading the stream can start working on the data before client is fully done sending it.

Does such a feature exist?

The only idea I have come up with is to have the client stream to a local file then send the server a URL to that file to stream from.

Comment: Do you really have to use a stream to achieve what you are trying to do ? You can use websockets for two way communication  between the client and the server. And you can send json messages one by one. http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can use java.nio(or Socket) to create a server and clients.

client read data and send the data(json?string?) to server one by one(or any other definite quantity)

when the data received by server then server start to process it. and client continue to read remaining data and continue to send it to server.

here are some example:
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/java-nio-socket-example/

my english is poor. Is this what you want to know?
i wish it can help you.

Comment: Right that is buffering. I'm looking for something that uses streaming *into* a service.

Comment: they have StreamingOutput for java rest. but there is no StreamingInput